# Content-Security-Policy meta tag preventing preload scanner to work properly in Chrome

Tags: html, performance, google-chrome

In the html body some stylesheets and javasripts are linked, i would expect the main parser to pause the parsing/rendering till each is loaded and executed, but in the meantime the preload scanner to request all the other resources in parallel (or at least discover an queue them). This can be observed in the network waterfall chart:

[image]

But when `Content-Security-Policy` as http equivalent meta tag (e.g. `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self';">`) is added, then suddenlty request are happening in sequense:

[image]

which to me looks like that not the preload scanner but rather the main parser is finding and requesting them. Is there a good reason why this should happen this way (firefox desn't seem to change behavior when the meta tag is present. also in chrome if CSP is a http header and not a meta tag, then browser behave normal)? Or is this some kind of bug?

markup:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self';">
  </head>
  <body>
    <link href="./css/a.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="./css/b.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="./css/c.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="./js/blocking.js"></script>
    <link href="./css/d.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <img src="./media/image.jpg" alt="alt">
    <h1>END</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

if the markup is much more complex, then the requests are partially in parallel and some in sequence. but not in the order of occurrence in the HTML. e.g. a.css and c.css in parallel, but b.css is requested after a.css is fully loaded.

page to test:
https://playground-70310.web.app/csp/test.html
without the meta tag:
https://playground-70310.web.app/csp/default.html